# ASP.Net How would I go about grabbing a directories file's names and sending them to a listbox with a value?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox

I have a pretty big project and am currently having troubles putting a list of directory values into a listbox.

In my code I am calling forth DirectoryInfo

```
Dim diFiles As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/songs/"))
lstFiles.DataSource = diFiles.GetFiles("*.mp3")
lstFiles.DataBind()
```

However when I use lstFiles.SelectedIndex I get "null" and for "lstFiles.SelectedValue" I get Null aswell. However for "lstFiles.SelectedItem" I get "-1" on everything I select. How would I assign the values to the listbox?

Comment: Loop through diFiles and add each item to the list.  if you don't set a value when you set the item, SelectedValue will always be null.

Comment: how do I go about adding values for every instance?

Comment: lstFiles.Items.Add(new ListItem(Visible Text, Value)) <-- this will allow you to use SelectedValue and get a non-null value

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are doing is correct to fill a `ListBox` with directory values.
Once you `DataBind`, the ListBox is bound to DataSource, and the `SelectedIndex` property is set to its default value (-1). Since no item is now selected, consequently the `SelectedValue` will also be Empty String, and `SelectedItem` will be Nothing (null).

In your case, since you are binding it with an array, each item has the same value as its displayed text, i.e. the filename.

You can simply set the `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedValue` to a valid value to select the desired item in the ListBox.

So, for example, the following code will cause the 2nd item in the ListBox to be selected after filling it with your mp3 filenames:

```
Dim diFiles As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/songs/"))
lstFiles.DataSource = diFiles.GetFiles("*.mp3")
lstFiles.DataBind()
lstFiles.SelectedIndex = 1   '-- this is assuming that there are atleast 2 items in the ListBox.
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking through help from @MaCron 's suggestion I was able to find out how to do this.

I set

```
Dim diFiles As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPatch("~/songs/"))
```

and set my listbox lsdFiles data source as only mp3's

```
lstFiles.DataSource = diFiles.GetFiles("*.mp3")
```

as which as set

```
Dim fri as FileInfo
```

and lastly made a "For each" statement to add the items into the listbox 1 by 1

```
For Each fri In lstFiles.DataSource
        ListBox1.Items.Add(fri.ToString)
    Next
```